# automatic encoding of all strings in a pandas dataframe.dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

i want to print on screen a dataframe.dtypes with a utf-8 encoding because a number of the dataframe's columns have non-unicode characters.

what works for me now is that i loop each column's name and use something like:

```
col.encode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

but i need the:

```
print(str(dataframe.dtypes))
```

because it prints a nice aligned list of columns along with each column's dtype.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and explain what output you would like?  It sounds like you want the types of the underlying objects, not the dtypes.  The dtype is `object` regardless of if the underlying object is a `bytes` or `str`.  Is something like `dataframe.applymap(type).drop_duplicates()` what you're looking for?

Comment: i want the output of "print(str(df.dtypes))" which gives something like:
Concept ID                                              uint16
Model ID                                                  category
Cell                                                          category
Fuse                                                        category
....                                                             .....                                                                                                                          to be able to print the non-unicode column names if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0,0],[0,1,2]], columns=['one', 'two', b'\x80abc'])
df.columns = np.char.decode(df.columns.values.astype(str), encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
print(str(df.dtypes))
```

I think, the only way is converting columns names before printing dtypes. But you can do it with this function `np.char.decode`.

Comment: your code almost works, you just need np.char.encode not decode since you are working on a string (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_char_decode.htm)